# JavaFX - scroll a scrollPane while button pressed

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a scrollPane that can be scrolled by pressing a button, using the following code

```
@FXML
public void scrollUp(ActionEvent event) {
    if (scrollPane.getVvalue() > scrollPane.getVmin()) {
        scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue() - scrollPaneIncrement);
    }
}

@FXML
public void scrollDown(ActionEvent event) {
    if (scrollPane.getVvalue() < scrollPane.getVmax()) {
        scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue() + scrollPaneIncrement);
    }
}
```

These functions are called from the onAction event when a button is pressed.

Now i need to scroll the scrollPane up and down for as long as the buttons are pressed.

Anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: I would start scrolling on a button press event, and stop scrolling on a button released event (or if the mouse is moved off the button). Use a timer to call the code to scroll at an interval.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AnimationTimer` to update the scroll position on each rendering frame. You can check whether the buttons are pressed using the `isArmed()` method, and update the scroller's value accordingly.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollWhileButtonDown extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinHeight(1000);
        scroller.setContent(pane);

        Button upButton = new Button("Up");
        Button downButton = new Button("Down");

        HBox controls = new HBox(10, upButton, downButton);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, controls, null), 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        final double scrollSpeed = 0.5 ; // scrollpane units per second

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            private long lastUpdate = 0 ;
            @Override
            public void handle(long time) {
                if (lastUpdate > 0) {
                    long elapsedNanos = time - lastUpdate ;
                    double elapsedSeconds = elapsedNanos / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                    double delta = 0 ;
                    if (upButton.isArmed()) {
                        delta = -scrollSpeed * elapsedSeconds ;
                    }
                    if (downButton.isArmed()) {
                        delta = scrollSpeed * elapsedSeconds ;
                    }
                    double newValue = 
                            clamp(scroller.getVvalue() + delta, scroller.getVmin(), scroller.getVmax());
                    scroller.setVvalue(newValue);
                }
                lastUpdate = time ;
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }

    private double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {
        return Math.min(max, Math.max(min, value));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: My new hobby: rewriting James's answers using ReactFX ;)

Comment: I was wondering why it took you so long... ;). I should note it's not too hard to start and stop the animation timer based on the armed state of the buttons; though the code gets a bit repetitive without `EventStream`s. (And there are obvious optimizations that can be made in the current `handle` method even without that.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my variation on @James_D's answer using [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) (version 2.0-M2 or higher). While it is not much more concise, it may be easier to read if you are familiar with `EventStream`s. It has the added benefit that the (hidden) animation timer is only firing when one of the buttons is pressed, not all the time. This is achieved by the trick of switching to observing a special stream `never()` when no button is pressed, which incurs no runtime costs. You can observe a slightly lower CPU usage when not scrolling.

```
import static org.reactfx.EventStreams.*;
import static org.reactfx.util.Tuples.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.reactfx.EventStream;

public class ScrollWhileButtonDown extends Application {

    private static enum BTN { UP, DOWN, NONE }

    private static final double scrollSpeed = 0.5 ; // scrollpane units per second

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinHeight(1000);
        scroller.setContent(pane);

        Button upButton = new Button("Up");
        Button downButton = new Button("Down");

        HBox controls = new HBox(10, upButton, downButton);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, controls, null), 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        EventStream<BTN> armedButtons = merge(
                valuesOf(upButton  .armedProperty()).map(armed -> armed ? BTN.UP   : BTN.NONE),
                valuesOf(downButton.armedProperty()).map(armed -> armed ? BTN.DOWN : BTN.NONE));

        EventStream<Double> deltas = armedButtons.flatMap(btn -> {
            switch(btn) {
                case UP:   return elapsedSeconds().map(sec -> sec * -scrollSpeed);
                case DOWN: return elapsedSeconds().map(sec -> sec *  scrollSpeed);
                default:   return never();
            }
        });

        deltas.subscribe(delta -> scroller.setVvalue(scroller.getVvalue() + delta));
    }

    private static EventStream<Double> elapsedSeconds() {
        return animationTicks()
                .accumulate(t(0L, -1L), (state, now) -> state.map((d, last) -> {
                        return t(last == -1L ? 0L : now - last, now);
                }))
                .map(t -> t._1 / 1_000_000_000.0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty slick, though I had to fight pretty hard to understand the `elapsedSeconds()` method.

Comment: @James_D Yeah, that one is pretty cryptic. This is partly due to the heavy use of ReactFX specific things like `animationTicks`, `accumulate`, `Tuple2.map`, and partly due to Java's lack of syntactic support for tuples and pattern matching that you get in many other languages. Anyway, treating it as a black box that returns a stream of durations elapsed since the last frame should be sufficient to understand the rest.

Comment: @James_D A helper method like this (it really is "just" a wrapper around `animationTicks`) is a good candidate for inclusion in the next release.

Comment: Yeah, I did figure it out, just took a little while. Probably didn't help that the ReactFX docs already open in one of my (30+) browser tabs was an older version that didn't have `animationTicks()`. I'm not a big user of `EventStream`s; but I wonder if an `EventStream.skip(long n)` method would be useful in general (returns a stream that ignores the first `n` events). That way I think you could just map the first `animationTick` to anything and then ignore it easily...

Comment: @James_D Makes sense to me. The thing to figure out is what semantics it should have in the presence of multiple subscribers. If you have an `EventStream<T> skipper = src.skip(8)` and then the second subscriber subscribes when 4 events were already skipped for the first subscriber, how many events should be skipped for the second subscriber, 4 or 8? Both semantics are easy to implement, the hard part is to choose one. In `elapsedSeconds` it makes sense to not skip an event if the stream is already "warmed up", but will it always be the case?

Comment: Good question. I think to me it makes more intuitive sense that subsequent subscribers "pick up where the stream is at", so in your example the second subscriber would skip 4 events. But as I said, I'm not a big user of reactive programming techniques, so the reactive programming community may have a different interpretation. Or perhaps the ambiguity is just a sign that this is not a sensible thing to add to the API at all?

Comment: @James_D The same question arises in other places as well. I try to avoid resolving it whenever possible. Your resolution also makes sense from the following perspective: If someone gives me a stream and I have no idea how it was constructed (e.g. using `skip`), then I cannot make any useful assumptions about when it starts emitting events, anyway. It should therefore depend solely on the stream's state. RxJava, however, does the opposite in this case (I just checked).